# C++11 match_regex doesn't match a simple pattern

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, match

I've been having some trouble with the new regular expression library in C++. Here's a simple example:

```
#include<regex>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string text = "123.456";
    string pattern = "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+";
    try{
        cout << (regex_match(text, regex(pattern, regex_constants::extended)) ? "Pass\n" : "Fail\n");
    }catch(...){
        cout << "Fail (bad regex)\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, no matter what type of matching I use (simple, extended, grep, egrep, awk, etc.), it always returns false. If I use "regex_constants::simple" it throws an exception, because bracketed expressions are not supported, but I checked the specs and it should work fine with "regex_constants::extended".

This is the result:

```
rhobincu@daneel:~/work$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
rhobincu@daneel:~/work$ ./test 
Fail
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: This might be useful info as well:

```
rhobincu@daneel:~/work$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: As a guess, the culprit is probably gcc's "implementation" of regular expressions: everything compiles but nothing works. They say that with version 4.9 things should be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`regex` is not yet supported in [GCC's libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x), [current status](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Regex/Status).

You can just replace `std::regex` with `boost::regex` and it compiles and works fine.

Comment: Great! So there's documentation and tutorials for using <regex> but it doesn't actually work... Wasted a full weekend in this. Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, it probably works in other compilers with other standard libraries :) AFAIK, under Linux even `clang` usually uses `GCC`'s `libstdc++` and thus it fails as well. But on other platforms, `clang` uses it's own std. library (`libc++`) and it should support `regex` there. I don't know if it's possible to get `clang` with `libc++` in Ubuntu, though.

Comment: @rhobincu if you're not afraid of installing from source, `svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk libcxx; cd libcxx/lib; ./buildit`. I get a `Pass` with my clang++/libc++ setup on linux.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However I'm one of many devs for this project and it's easier to ask them to install boost than compile libc.